# How do I merge two meshes with high density and different structure?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

First of all, I have never used Blender nor any other modelling software before. I have seen a lot of solutions showing how to merge verticies and join objects together, however I'm curious if there is any solution not including merging hundreds of vericies one-by-one and still resulting in one mesh. I'm going to 3D print the object, that's why joinink only the objects together is a no-go.

Here is a picture how the two meshes overlap each other:
[image: overlaping]

And a close-up:
[image: close-up]

Can anyone help me with this please? I am using Blender 2.91.0.

Comment: you need to look into the Boolean modifier (Union mode), try the 2 solvers, Exact or Fast, it may bug for some reasons though, depending on the quality of your mesh

Comment: That didn't work unfortunatelly, somehow the mesh the Boolean was applied to disappeared, I ended up starting over :/

Comment: maybe share your file so that some people can test? (i'm afraid i won't be able with my own computer though) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Unfortunatelly I started over the same file I was stuck with, and I don't think I can recreate the situation, bad thing I haven't though about making a copy of the file.. Guess it remains a mistery

Answer (score 0):

The example looks straight so I think this case is resolved by joining both objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> then selecting all the edges that you want to merge.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and then scaling it in the perpendicular axis with <kbd>S</kbd>+(<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> depending which axis is perpendicular). Once it is all together, use <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge by a Distance*. That should do the job in this case since it is all straight.